# How to change default separate (divide) in theme of android 3.0 + version?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I've got one problem. I use the actionbarsherlock library. I have a green actionbar and I want to use a green theme for all of my application.
How can I change the blue to green? It's desirable for throughout the application.
[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. DatePicker consists of CalendarView and NumberPicker. CalendarView be easy to design, but NumberPicker anymore, since he attributes are private and should not find the approach. The only option was to completely rewrite this widget DatePicker from scratch, but it is very time-consuming work. Good thing I found a library HoloEverywhere, there guys have done all this, and I could only replace the icons/pictures on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You can style it like this:

```
<style name="myStyle" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
     <item name="android:calendarViewStyle">@style/myCalendarView</item>
</style>

<style name="myCalendarView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.CalendarView">
     <item name="android:selectedDateVerticalBar">@drawable/myDivider</item>
</style>
```

The default divider is this:

[image]

Just change the color to green and voilà you'll have your green divider.

Comment: Thanks! But I could not to change divider of numberpicker's. Attribute android:selectionDivider of NumberPicker is private and I can't change blue divider. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

using this code :

```
Field[] pickerFields = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field pf : pickerFields) {
            if (pf.getName().equals("mSelectionDivider")) {
                pf.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    pf.set(daypicker, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent)));//you can use all colors
                    pf.set(mounthpicker, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent)));
                    pf.set(yearpicker, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent)));
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
```